# Scrolling RecyclerView according to another RecyclerView item position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an horizontal recyclerView (Category Recyclerview) at the top of the screen that contains Titles, below it there is another vertical recyclerView (Category Items) that contains Titles and sub recyclerView that contains each title's items.

I need to make the Horizontal recyclerview (Category Recyclerview) scroll to specific title according to the last displayed title in the vertical recyclerview (Category Items).

Here is the code i follow, it does work but not efficient as expected
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [LinearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager#findlastvisibleitemposition) and [LinearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager#scrolltoposition)

Something like:

```
fun myFunction() {
    val lastDisplayedTitleIndex = verticalLinearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
    val horizontalItemIndex = figureOutHorizontalItemIndexFromLastVerticalVisibleItemIndex(lastDisplayedTitleIndex)
    horizontalLinearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(horizontalItemIndex)
}

private fun figureOutHorizontalItemIndexFromLastVerticalVisibleItemIndex(index: Int) {
    // YOUR LOGIC HERE
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I do use these methods and it does scroll but in some cases it doesn't work properly !